# Three JS - problems while rendering a scene v71 in some browsers

Tags: javascript, three.js

Using three.js v71, I'm trying to add a meshphong material and display it on-screen after adding material caps. When I try to render it on Chrome v42.0 (Linux) it works fine. But when I try to run it on Chrome v42.0, I get an error pointing to the library file

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

I get an error at the same place when I run it on Firefox DE (v39) and on Firefox SE (v37) with the message

**TypeError: a.defaultAttributeValues[h] is undefined**

Is it because of synchronization issues in the js code (assigning properties to an undefined object)? And also how does it render correctly on the Linux browser and not on other platforms?

Comment: The loading of textures/models is asynchronous so it might be the case that in one machine it has time to download and use the assets while on the other it doesn't. But without showing any code it is hard to tell. Post the code relevant to the loading of assets.

Comment: @gaitat - here's the link. TIA. --> https://gist.github.com/bizentass/73ee270906c94e6e5b6d#file-gistfile1-js

Comment: `controls.update()` is not needed. Remove the `needsUpdate` flags. Why are you setting the material twice? Paste the relevant code in the body of the post and link to a live example. But first, use the non-minified version of three.js for debugging, and debug the code yourself.

Comment: @WestLangley thank you for the advice on debugging with the non-minified code. That pointed out the issue clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue with a small change to the three.js library code.

In the three.js (v71) line no. 20263, I included the [key] in the if condition

```
} else if ( material.defaultAttributeValues[ key ] !== undefined ) {
```

In the same way, in three.min.js (v71) line no. 443, I included the key which is [h] in the if condition

```
0!==a.defaultAttributeValues[h]
```

This fixed the issue and the object is now rendered properly in both the browsers.

Comment: That is a really bad idea. Most likely, your application is doing something inappropriate.

Comment: @WestLangley, yes I shouldn't be meddling with the source code, will debug my application further. Thanks again.